I couldn't start Tensorflow Object Detection API training with Google colab's TPUv2
I am using version of Tensorflow 2.15.0 and Python 3.10.12 in google colab cell
    tpu = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(tpu='local')
    tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(tpu)
    tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(tpu)


is running but ;

!python /content/models/research/object_detection/model_main_tf2.py \
--pipeline_config_path={TRAIN_FOLDER}/pipeline.config \
--model_dir={TRAIN_FOLDER}/model/checkpoint/ \
--num_train_steps=20000 \
--num_eval_steps=1000 \
--sample_1_of_n_eval_examples=10 \
--use_tpu={True} \`

!python /content/models/research/object_detection/model_main_tf2.py \ relevant part

...
if FLAGS.use_tpu:
      # TPU is automatically inferred if tpu_name is None and
      # we are running under cloud ai-platform.
      resolver = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(
          tpu='local')
      tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(resolver)
      tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(resolver)
      strategy = tf.distribute.experimental.TPUStrategy(resolver)
    elif FLAGS.num_workers > 1:
      strategy = tf.distribute.experimental.MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy()
    else:
      strategy = tf.compat.v2.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
...

I'm getting errors while start training.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/content/models/research/object_detection/model_main_tf2.py", line 114, in
tf.compat.v1.app.run()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 36, in run
_run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 308, in run
_run_main(main, args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 254, in _run_main
sys.exit(main(argv))
File "/content/models/research/object_detection/model_main_tf2.py", line 97, in main
tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(resolver)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/cluster_resolver/tpu/tpu_cluster_resolver.py", line 72, in initialize_tpu_system
return tpu_strategy_util.initialize_tpu_system_impl(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/tpu/tpu_strategy_util.py", line 142, in initialize_tpu_system_impl
raise errors.NotFoundError(
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: TPUs not found in the cluster. Failed in initialization: No matching devices found for '/device:TPU_SYSTEM:0' [Op:__inference__tpu_init_fn_4]

I'm using multiple TPUv2 and I can't start training because I can't connect
I tried Tensorflow version 2.13.0 also
    tpu = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(tpu='local')
    tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(tpu)
    tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(tpu)


The specified Code block does not work in the terminal while it is running in the Colab cell.
